# How to write the hamiltonian for w state?

Tags: hamiltonian

Suppose the $w$ stare

$|w\rangle=(1/3)^{½}(|100\rangle+|010\rangle+|001\rangle) $

Let's say the eigenvalues of this state are $k_i$ then the hamiltonian corresponding to it is as follows:

$H =k_1 |100\rangle \langle100|+k_2 |010\rangle\langle010| + k_3|001\rangle \langle001| $

Am i right?

Also i want to know are the eigenvalues of a state the same as eigenvalues of energy? Or they are different?

Comment: What do you mean by *hamiltonian for a state*?

Comment: I mean the W state

Comment: You are confusing a matrix with a vector. The state is a vector. A Hamiltonian is a hermitian operator, e.g. a matrix. The W state is indeed an eigenvector of a Hamiltonian. Perhaps you are asking how to define a Hamiltonian to which W is a eigenvector. Its eigenvalue will then be the (scalar) value satisfying the corresponding Schrödinger equation.

Comment: I really dont know the difference between eigenvalues of a hamiltonian and eigenvalues of a density matrix. What do they show?

Comment: What do you mean "hamiltonian for w state". Do you mean "the hamiltonian that creates the w state, starting from an initial state of |000\rangle$"? Or perhaps "the Hamiltonian that was the w state as its unique ground state"? Or something else?

Comment: @DaftWullie yes its what i mean. The hamiltonian that creates w state...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand from the comments that the question is really to find a Hamiltonian $H$ and a corresponding time $t$ such that
$$
e^{-iHt}|000\rangle=|w\rangle
$$
where
$$
|w\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(|001\rangle+|010\rangle+|100\rangle).
$$

There are many Hamiltonians that do this job. The process that I would take is as follows: First, we define the unitary evolution that we want,
$$
U|000\rangle=|w\rangle.
$$
This does not completely define the unitary: we need to specify how it acts on an orthonormal basis. So, we have lots of freedom to complete it. There are many different criteria that you might apply at this point. To make things as mathematically simple as possible, I want $U$ to have a very simple spectrum. It's already non-simple in a two-dimensional subspace spanned by $|000\rangle$ and $|w\rangle$, but perhaps everything else could be the boring identity? Thus, we'd have
$$
U=|w\rangle\langle 000|-|000\rangle\langle w|+(I-|000\rangle\langle 000|-|w\rangle\langle w|).
$$
To translate into a Hamiltonian, we just need to identify eigenvalues $e^{i\theta}$ of $U$, and make them correspond to eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $H$ (same eigenvectors) such that $e^{-i\lambda t}=e^{i\theta}$. In particular, everything in the identity block, I can just select to have $\lambda=0$. Hence, we can have a Hamiltonian of the form
$$
H=-\frac{\pi}{2t}(|w\rangle\langle 000|-|000\rangle\langle w|).
$$
Note that in the two-dimensional subspace, this acts like the evolution of a Pauli $Y$ matrix,
$$
e^{-i\pi Y/2}=iY,
$$
which is what we were asking for.

Alternatively, you might want to look for a Hamiltonian that is as simple as possible in terms of being able to decompose it only in terms of two-body terms. That's typically a much more awkward optimisation, which I haven't tried (I don't even know if a solution exists). However, I will note that
$$
e^{-i(X_1X_2+Y_2Y_2+X_1X_3+Y_1Y_3)t}|100\rangle=|w\rangle
$$
if we select $t$ such that $\cos(2\sqrt{2}t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ (but this uses a slightly different initial state).